# Crop a Video file with diverse Aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, video, crop, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to give my users the possibility to crop their video in diverse aspect ratio before uploading them on my fireplace database. I'm using an [Android-VideoCropView](https://github.com/crust87/Android-VideoCropView) for display the video editor layout for my users and [SimpleVideoEditor](https://github.com/fahimfarhan/SimpleVideoEditor) to crop the video.However, I'm having a hard time to merge both library together when I'm trying to get the info from the [VideoCropView](https://github.com/crust87/Android-VideoCropView) and then crop the file with the [SimpleVideoEditor](https://github.com/fahimfarhan/SimpleVideoEditor) this is [the result I should have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5d0A.jpg) and this is [the result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0itp.jpg). So my question is what I'm doing bad and how can I fix that?

Here is my Code

```
     Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(stringvideofile));
                                        String destPath = getVideoFilePath();


                                        //1.
                                        float baseWidthPx =  mVideoCropView.getVideoWidth();    // should be +// todo: match every views one side , then set that side. need an if-else
                                        float  baseHeightPx = mVideoCropView.getVideoHeight() ;
                                        // 2. get the center of crop quad
                                        float  cropQuadCenterX, cropQuadCenterY;
                                        cropQuadCenterX = mVideoCropView.getRealPositionX() + baseWidthPx/2;
                                        cropQuadCenterY = mVideoCropView.getRealPositionY() + baseHeightPx/2;

                                        // 3. get video frame quad center
                                        float  videoQuadCenterX, videoQuadCenterY;
                                        videoQuadCenterX =  mVideoCropView.getWidth()/2;
                                        videoQuadCenterY = mVideoCropView.getHeight()/2;

                                        float dx = videoQuadCenterX - cropQuadCenterX;
                                        float dy = videoQuadCenterY - cropQuadCenterY;

                                        dx = 2*dx/baseWidthPx;  // idk why multiply with 2 :/ divide with baseSizePx to get ratio, that makes sense but why 2???
                                        dy = 2*dy/baseHeightPx;

                                        float translateX = dx, translateY = dy;

                                        FillModeCustomItem fillModeCustomItem = new FillModeCustomItem(
                                                mVideoCropView.getScaleX(),
                                                mVideoCropView.getRotate(),
                                                translateX,
                                                translateY,
                                                mVideoCropView.getVideoWidth(),
                                                mVideoCropView.getVideoHeight()
                                        );


                                       GlFilterGroup glFilterGroup;
                                        if(composerGlFilter == null) {
                                         composerGlFilter = new GlFilter();
                                        }

                                        glFilterGroup  = new GlFilterGroup(new GlFilter()); // the default filter
                                        Log.e(TAG, "currentGlFilter is null");



                                        final Logger mylogger = new Logger() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void debug(String tag, String message) {
                                                Log.d(tag, message);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void error(String tag, String message, Throwable error) {
                                                Log.e(tag, "Message: "+message + ". Error: "+error.getLocalizedMessage());
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void warning(String tag, String message) {
                                                Log.w(tag, message);
                                            }
                                        };


                                        mp4Composer = null;
                                        mp4Composer = new Mp4Composer(fileUri, destPath, CropVideoActivity.this, mylogger);
                                        mp4Composer
                                                .size(mVideoCropView.getWidth(), mVideoCropView.getHeight()) // fake it till you make it
                                                .fillMode(FillMode.CUSTOM)
                                                .customFillMode(fillModeCustomItem);



                                        if(composerGlFilter != null){
                                            mp4Composer.filter(composerGlFilter);
                                        }else{
                                            mp4Composer.filter(glFilterGroup);
                                        }

                                        mp4Composer.trim(mStartTimeMs,  mVideoCropView.getDuration())
                                                .listener(new Mp4Composer.Listener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onProgress(double progress) {
                                                        Log.d(TAG, "onProgress = " + progress);
                                                        new Thread()
                                                        {
                                                            public void run()
                                                            {
                                                                CropVideoActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                                                {
                                                                    public void run()
                                                                    {
                                                                        //Do your UI operations like dialog opening or Toast here
                                                                        Toast.makeText( CropVideoActivity.this, "onProgress = " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        }.start();
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCompleted() {
                                                        Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted()");

                                                        new Thread()
                                                        {
                                                            public void run()
                                                            {
                                                                CropVideoActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                                                {
                                                                    public void run()
                                                                    {
                                                                        //Do your UI operations like dialog opening or Toast here
                                                                        Toast.makeText( CropVideoActivity.this, "codec complete path = " + destPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        }.start();
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCanceled() {
                                                        Log.d(TAG, "onCanceled");

                                                        new Thread()
                                                        {
                                                            public void run()
                                                            {
                                                                CropVideoActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                                                {
                                                                    public void run()
                                                                    {
                                                                        //Do your UI operations like dialog opening or Toast here
                                                                        Toast.makeText( CropVideoActivity.this, "videoProcessing onCanceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        }.start();
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onFailed(Exception exception) {
                                                        Log.e(TAG, "onFailed()", exception);

                                                        new Thread()
                                                        {
                                                            public void run()
                                                            {
                                                                CropVideoActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                                                {
                                                                    public void run()
                                                                    {
                                                                        //Do your UI operations like dialog opening or Toast here
                                                                        Toast.makeText( CropVideoActivity.this, "exception.getMessage()  : "+exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        }.start();

                                                    }
                                                });

                                        mp4Composer.start();
```

Comment: Did You Tried with different device?

Comment: @EmonHossainMunna no only with an Honor 9X pro